# compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0" erro

Tags: android-studio

Essa mensagem aparece no console do Android Studio

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
>   It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

E aponta para a linha 156 da imagem abaixo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como corrijo isso? Já acessei o link indicado no console, mas abra um página cheio de explicações e nada que parece ser a solução.

Comment: Trocar o `compile` por `implementation` e colocar a versão no lugar do `+` não resolveu?

Comment: Sim, deu certo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A documentação tem uma lista de quais diretivas devem ser usadas no lugar das obsoletas e recomenda utilizar o número da versão exato para evitar problemas de dependências dinâmicas. No caso mude `compile` por `implementation`